# The fate of flags of deleted answers

Tags: support, flagging

I feel like this is very much related to [Deleted posts don't clear from flag cache](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8380/deleted-posts-dont-clear-from-flag-cache)

In any case....  What happens to flags when an answer, for example, is deleted by the user (and not by a third party moderator who's reviewed the flag(s))?  Additionally, does this affect your flagging history (will/should the flag be considered helpful automatically)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mods still see the flags. (And this tacitly answers the second half of your question).

Comment: Thanks... I know this isn't a particularly interesting question, but I was curious and couldn't find the answer.